# can't call function in smart contract tron blockchain

Tags: blockchain, tron

I have a contract on the shasta test network. I create a contract inside my smart contract and save its address in an array, but i can't call function(i use tronweb) from contract which i create in smart contract. how  i can call functions from contracts which created first contract? please help me. thanks

i can call functions from first smart contract which i created, but  i cant call functions from contract which created first contract

[link for shasta](https://shasta.tronscan.org/#/contract/TFWss73HdRqiA8RJuBaBAuiXYifXLidmiK/code) it is  contract which created first contract and [link for shasta](https://shasta.tronscan.org/#/contract/TM1KE9o2Zr7huCf2cgSQGcyxf46v19vjmM/code) it is  first contract

Comment: Same question. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @Justin Tron does not support creating a smart contract inside a smart contract.

Comment: Yes they are, you have to use [transaction builder](https://developers.tron.network/reference#triggersmartcontract) to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use transaction builder to do that:

- For `.send()` like: https://developers.tron.network/reference#triggersmartcontract
- `.call()` like: https://developers.tron.network/reference#triggerconstantcontract-1